# intent.resolveActivity() returning null for ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, sms

When a user clicks a button in my app, I want to launch the default SMS app on their device with a fixed phone number as well as a sample text.

To achieve this, I decided to follow [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#SendMessage). I used the exact function that's in the sample code:

```
fun composeMmsMessage() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        data = Uri.parse("smsto:+2340000000000")  // I used a valid phone number in my actual code
        putExtra("sms_body", "Hi there!")
    }
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

I think it's also worth mentioning that I am running this from a fragment and I think `packageManager` is tied to the activity. Also, I have tested this app on three different devices (Two Kitkats, one Oreo).

However, I noticed that `intent.resolveActivity(packageManager)` is ALWAYS null. Hence, this never works. Is there a better way to do this than what's in the official docs?

Comment: Just want to make sure, the device, you are running ur app into has any sms app?

Comment: @akashzincle Yes, it does. I've tried this app on three other devices; same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple fix that works like a charm:

```
fun composeMmsMessage() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", "+2340000000000", null)).apply {
        putExtra("sms_body", "Hi there!")
    }
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once, instead of ACTION_SEND, use ACTION_SENDTO

```
fun composeMmsMessage() {
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
    data = Uri.parse("smsto:+2340000000000")  // I used a valid phone number in my actual code
    putExtra("sms_body", "Hi there!")
}
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

}